# Counting number of repeated items in a while loop

Tags: php

I have a script which polls data from the database; within my `while loop` I am trying to (count) the number of account numbers that appears multiple times but I was having count based on the number of records fetched.

```
 $itemArray = array();
 $check = array();
$amount = array(); 
while ($row =  sqlsrv_fetch_array($empRecords, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)) {

   $itemArray[] = $row['ac_no']; 
   $amount[] = $row['accountBalance']; 

    foreach ($itemArray as $cust_no)
    {
        if (isset($result[$cust_no]))
        {
            $result[$cust_no]++;
        }
        else
        {
            $result[$cust_no] = 1;
        }
    }

    foreach ($result as $cust_no => $count)
    {
        echo "{$cust_no}: {$count}" . "<br/>";
    }

}
```

if you take a look at customer number **100001** it appears only 4 times; sample diagram below:

[database query sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nty5B.png)

But within my while loop, the details appears per number of all members; also for others.

[Data display](https://i.stack.imgur.com/idsx3.png)

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Your foreach loops probably need to be outside the while loop, this is processing all of the  previous data each time round the loop.

Comment: @NigelRen, it's needed within the while loop. I need to sum its values and populate it into a dataTable

Comment: You need to populate `$itemArray` inside the while loop, but `$result` after it. Additionally, `$result = array_count_values($itemArray);` might yield the same result as your foreach loop.

Answer (score 0):

You're counting way too much if you iterate the `$itemArray` over and over... each ac_no is counted multiple times.

That is all you need:

```
$itemArray = array();
$amount = array(); 
$result = array();
while ($row =  sqlsrv_fetch_array($empRecords, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    $ac_no = $row['ac_no'];
    
    $itemArray[] = $ac_no; 
    $amount[] = $row['accountBalance']; 

    if (!isset($result[$ac_no])) {
        $result[ $ac_no ] = 0;
    }
    $result[ $ac_no ]++;
}

foreach ($result as $cust_no => $count) {
    echo "{$cust_no}: {$count}" . "<br/>";
}
```